# When exception is thrown from restcontroller, intellij and jar built by gradle have different results

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

```
package refill.station.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        throw new NullPointerException("test Exception");
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown with 'test Exception' message in TestController.
When I run this code with intellij, I can check my error message in response!
I checked it with postman. Look!
[image]

We can see message in response.
This message is used as alert message with axios!!

But I can't see the message, when I run this code as jar built by `gradle build` command!
Here is the result in postman.
[image]

Message is empty, as well as the error is an Internal server error!

Answer (score 1):

To get the unique Response message, then return the jax Response Object instead of Void in test method.
Here is a sample code.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Response test() {
        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        try {
            processReqest();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.setResponseText(ex.getMessage());
            return Response.ok(response).status(200).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(response).status(200).build();
    }

    private void processReqest() {
        throw new NullPointerException("test Exception");       
    }
}

class MyResponse implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3015657137609271996L;
    private String responseText;
    public String getResponseText() {
        return responseText;
    }
    public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
        this.responseText = responseText;
    }
}
```